# Bootstrap popover with <div></div> and contents with ""

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I successfully implemented the Bootstrap popover after some trying...

Now I want to implement another HTML into the popover. Normal Tags like `<p align=center>some text</p>` 
are working, but if I add some quotes, it doesen't work anymore:

```
<a href="link" rel="popover" data-content="<img src="pathToSource/img.png">" data-placement="top">...</a>
```

Then I tried this:

```
<a href="link" rel="popover" data-content="<img src=\"pathToSource/img.png\">" data-placement="top">...</a>
```

I also tried to replace the content of the data-content-attribute with `<?PHP echo '...' ?>` but that didn't work too.

Can anyone help me please?

**Edit: Actual code**

```
<a href="myFacebookPage" rel="popover" data-content='<div style="width: 100px; height: 200px;" class="fb-like" data-href="myFacebookPage" data-layout="box_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>' data-placement="top" target="_blank">
    <img src="theUsedIcon"
</a>
```

Comment: How about using single quotes? `data-content="<img src='pathToSource/img.png'>"`

Comment: BTW, use CSS instead of `<p align=center>some text</p>`

Comment: Oh nice, it worked, the code on the site is now right, but the popover has no content, it says 0px x 0px and if I change it with style="height: 100px; width: 100px;", there is still no content...

Comment: As above don't use align=center, Bootstrap has a class that you can use called text-center so it would be like <p class="text-center">

Comment: Can you set up a Bootply? http://www.bootply.com/new

Comment: sorry I should be more specific <p align=center> was just an example, here's my code:
<code><a href="myFacebookPage" rel="popover" data-content='<div style="width: 100px; height: 200px;" class="fb-like" data-href="myFacebookPage" data-layout="box_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>' data-placement="top" target="_blank"><img src="theUsedIcon"</a></code>

Comment: I don't know if it is like this in your actual code but you are missing a closing > on your <img>

Comment: sorry I don't know how to use "<code></code>" on comments :D
the a tag has an image as content, if you click on it, you'll get to my facebook page, and if you only do mouseover, the popover appears and theres a like-button, but the like-button doesen't show...
the problem is not the like-button, it tested it before, it's  definitely a problem with the popover

Comment: Do you have an example page that I can see?

Comment: Don't forget, if you want to display HTML in the popover, you have to set data-html="true" in the popover markup or have {html: true} in the popover options in your javascript.

Answer (score 0):

In the [options](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers) for the popover you'll note that it states to use the html option set to true, because if false, jQuery's text method will be used to insert content into the DOM. It also warns that the default value is false, and you should use text if you're worried about XSS attacks.

So, try writing your link this way instead:

```
<a href="myFacebookPage" rel="popover" data-content='<div style="width: 100px; height: 200px;" class="fb-like" data-href="myFacebookPage" data-layout="box_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>' data-placement="top" target="_blank" data-html="true">
    <img src="theUsedIcon">
</a>
```

Comment: Yeah, so I was thinking that might be what you were trying to do.  That's why I said "try".  The facebook markup there needs some JS to run, usually it's run on the page load.  I don't see it anywhere on your Bootply, but on your site, you're going to probably have to trigger the facebook JS on the show.bs.popover or shown.bs.popover event.  At least, that's what I'd try.  The html has to be added to the DOM when the facebook JS is run.  Inside the data-content it's not part of the DOM is just a string.

Comment: If there's an iFrame option for the like button that you can use, you could also try that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks for your answers :)

I replaced the javascript Like-Button with the iFrame Like-Button and now it's working.